# Verve as a verb meaning "to enter into" or "venture"

Tags: word-usage, contemporary-english

I've recently come across examples of the word "verve" used as a verb meaning "to enter into or venture into. I thought the writers meant to use "veer" or "verge" but clearly this was meant in a positive way.
Has anyone come across this usage and know where or when it originates? Is it a straight-up error or a new usage that will soon be ubiquitous?

examples:
https://www.goodreads.com/review/show.html?id=35779413&page=2
http://www.nairaland.com/2436875/citi-bank-ready-consumer-banking
https://www.smogon.com/forums/threads/post-rock.37020/

Comment: 1st example looks like phone-entered with auto-correct (probably mean to say *verge*). 2nd example is not fluent English. 3rd example could again be auto-correct or just a typo (originally *veer*).

Comment: (or, if the 2nd example is fluent, it's in a dialect (Nigerian?) that has substantial differences from AmE or BrE)